# Python Multiprocessing within Jupyter Notebook does not work

Tags: python, multiprocessing, jupyter-notebook

I am new to `multiprocessing` module in Python and work with Jupyter notebooks.
When I try to run the following code I keep getting `AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'load' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>`

When I run the file there is no output, it just keeps loading.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import urllib
import requests
from pprint import pprint
import time
from io import StringIO
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool

symbols = ['AAP']

start = time.time()
dflist = []

def load(date):
    if date is None:
        return
    url = "http://regsho.finra.org/FNYXshvol{}.txt".format(date)
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(url,delimiter='|')
        if any(df['Symbol'].isin(symbols)):
            stocks = df[df['Symbol'].isin(symbols)]
            print(stocks.to_string(index=False, header=False))
            # Save stocks to mysql
        else:
            print(f'No stock found for {date}' )
    except urllib.error.HTTPError:
        pass

pool = []
numdays = 365
start_date = datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 15 )  #year - month - day
datelist = [
        (start_date - datetime.timedelta(days=x)).strftime('%Y%m%d') for x in range(0, numdays)
        ]

pool = Pool(processes=16)
pool.map(load, datelist)

pool.close()
pool.join()

print(time.time() - start)
```

What can I do to run this code directly from the notebook without issues?

Answer (score 1):

one way to do it:
1. get `load` function out and create for example `worker.py`
2. `import worker` and `worker.load`
3.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import worker
if __name__ ==  '__main__': 
  pool = []
  numdays = 365
  start_date = datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 15 )  #year - month - day
  datelist = [
        (start_date - datetime.timedelta(days=x)).strftime('%Y%m%d') for x in 
        range(0, numdays)
        ]

  pool = Pool(processes=16)
  pool.map(worker.load, datelist)

  pool.close()
  pool.join()
```

Comment: Seems to work, but I am unsure on how to save the output as a df now... @galaxyan