# How to run a function parallelly in python?

Tags: python, windows, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have the function Test below

```
import concurrent.futures
from multiprocessing import Pool

def Test(n):
    print(n)
```

which i want to run parallelly so I do this

```
li = ['a','b', 'c']
    
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(Test, li )
```

but I do not see the output i.e. printing a, b , c

I am running it on Jupyter notebook. not sure if that is the issue. I do not see any output. Although if i call test function individually it runs fine.

I am running it on Windows OS

Comment: Works fine for me, got `b a c`

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am not sure how I can make it more minimal than this. It is just a print function printing list values parallelly.

Comment: For starters, this code would raise a `NameError` since `concurrent` is not defined. You **really** must tell us exactly what you are doing. Give us the example of your code **exactly**, and tell us how you are running it **exactly**. Note, for multiprocessing, your operating system matters.

Comment: If I create an example based on the snippets here and run it myself, I get exactly what one would expect

Comment: @Guy does it have to do something with running it on a jupyter notebook? I ran the above code but I do not see any output

Comment: I'm not working with Jupyter and couldn't run the code at all in the online version (errors on the `multiprocessing` import), but I don't think it the reason, maybe the output is not where you expect it to be?

Comment: Do you see any error messages on Jupyter Notebook's log window? From my experience you have to have your worker function, `Test` in this case, in an external module that gets imported. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56350189/python-multiprocessing-within-jupyter-notebook-does-not-work). At least that has been the case for Windows. Questions tagged with `multiprocessing` are also supposed to be tagged with the platform your are running on. Please specify your platform, such as `windows` or `linux`. Place your cursor over the `multiprocessing` tag and read the text that pops up.

Comment: @Booboo no error messages. I do not think `Test` function needs to be in external module that needs to be imported. I am following this tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKl2JW_qrso and if we refer this code on github https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/blob/master/Python/MultiProcessing/process-images.py we can see function need not be in external module. I am using Windows OS.

Comment: @Stupid_Intern That tutorial is not specifically about Jupyter Notebook. And you still haven't specified what OS you are running under. If it's Windows it will not work unless you do as I suggest.

Comment: @Booboo I have mentioned it is Windows

Comment: @Stupid_Intern My apologies; I missed that; I was looking at the *tags*. And have you tried importing `Test` from. for example, a file named *test.py* with `from test import Test`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would normally issue a close vote on this as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56350189/python-multiprocessing-within-jupyter-notebook-does-not-work), but now that we have finally established that you are running under Windows, you have two issues with your code.

1. You need to import your worker function `Test` from an external file to use multiprocessing with Jupyter Notebook successfully. But multiprocessing code is best *not* run from Jupyter Notebook because of this complication and also because terminal output from your subprocesses that would normally be captured and written below the cell is instead written  to the Jupyter Notebook logging window (see below).
2. On platforms that launch new processes using the OS *spawn* method, such as Windows, you must enclose any code that creates new processes within a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block. In fact, you should place any code at global scope that is not required by your worker function in such a block for improved efficiency as it would otherwise be needlessly executed by every process in your pool as part of its initialization.

**File *test.py* in same directory as your .ipynb file**

```py
def Test(n):
    print(n)
```

**And your cell**

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from test import Test
    import concurrent.futures


    li = ['a','b', 'c']

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(Test, li )
```

Here is the output from the Jupyter Notebook logging window (here I am actually usually using Jupyter Lab, which is built on top of Jupyter Notebook):

```
[I 06:08:25.599 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 06:08:25.600 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is c:\program files\python38\share\jupyter\lab
[I 06:08:25.702 LabApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Booboo\test
[I 06:08:25.703 LabApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.1.5 is running at:
[I 06:08:25.706 LabApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=156f2a52135726b662215b349b4047dfea557c17d1acb366
[I 06:08:25.706 LabApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=156f2a52135726b662215b349b4047dfea557c17d1acb366
[I 06:08:25.707 LabApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 06:08:26.082 LabApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/Booboo/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-13472-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=156f2a52135726b662215b349b4047dfea557c17d1acb366
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=156f2a52135726b662215b349b4047dfea557c17d1acb366
[I 06:08:39.827 LabApp] Build is up to date
[I 06:08:58.745 LabApp] Kernel started: bac1f587-2c31-45e5-b1ca-7f56dd1929ba, name: python3
a
c
b
```

If `Test` were instead:

```py
def Test(n):
    return n * n
```

And your cell:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from test import Test
    import concurrent.futures


    li = [1, 2, 3]

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        print(list(executor.map(Test, li)))
```

Then the printing would be done by your main process and you *would* see the output beneath the cell.

You should also look at [PEP 8 – Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) when you have a chance. Function names are usually not started with uppercase letters.

Comment: I tried importing from external file, I still do not see any output.

Comment: Please re-read the entire updated the answer.